# Include Java EE after installed Eclipse platform binaries

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

How can I download Java EE runtime binary and install it on the eclipse platform binaries.
I saw that WTP exists, but I did not found its runtime binary.

I ask this question because I saw on that [post](http://fbksoft.com/6-tips-to-make-eclipse-lighter-prettier-and-more-efficient/) that in order to have my eclipse lighter, I have to install runtime binaries. But JDT does not allow to use servers.

Comment: Frankly I would dispute a lot of that blog, sticking to Eclipse 3.x at this point is crazy. Eclipse 4.6 will be released in just a few days time. The normal WTP install is the equivalent of the 'runtime binary'.

Comment: If you want to do some Java EE in Eclipse IDE, just pick the Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers... The goal of an IDE is not to be light, it's to be productive and to save your time; I'm not sure such optimizations will help you to take advantage of the IDE.

Comment: Ok many thanks for your advices :)